# How to extract a domain from a web address?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a list of webAddresses. I need to extract the domain name from the address.

**Sample of webAddress**

```
http://1life.co
http://1rage.com
http://1-solar.com
http://1stplayable.com
http://1velocity.net
http://microsoft.com
http://21cm.com
http://21csi.com
http://23half.com
http://2bsolutions.net
```

I need to retrieve this:

```
1life
1rage
1-solar
1stplayable
1velocity
microsoft
21cm
21csi
23half
2bsolutions
```

I tried looking at access string functions, but I couldn't find anything to help me.

My query needs to be like this:

```
SELECT function(webAddress)
FROM myTable
```

Comment: Are you looking for a query, or a VBA solution?

Comment: @Comintern, anything. If I use vba, I would like a function that I can use in a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Access RIGHT, LEFT, INSTR, and INSTRREV functions if you want to parse it out via SQL:

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(webAddress, LEN(webAddress) - INSTR(1, webAddress, "//") - 1), 
            INSTRREV(webAddress, ".") -  INSTR(1, webAddress, "//") - 2) FROM myTable;
```

Note that you can use almost the exact same logic in VBA (although caching the repeated calls to `InStr` would be better):

```
Public Function ExtractUrl(webAddress As String)
    ExtractUrl = Left$(Right$(webAddress, Len(webAddress) - InStr(1, webAddress, "//") - 1), _
                       InStrRev(webAddress, ".") - InStr(1, webAddress, "//") - 2)
End Function
```